# How to write $f(z) = \frac{1}{\left(z-3\right)\left(z-4\right)\left(z-5\right)}$ as a Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, laurent-series

I have the following function:

$f(z) = \frac{1}{\left(z-3\right)\left(z-4\right)\left(z-5\right)}$

Through partial fractions I got the values of A, B and C as below:

$=\frac{A}{(z-3)} + \frac{B}{(z-4)} + \frac{C}{(z-5)}$

$A = \frac{1}{2}$, $B=-1$, $C = \frac{1}{2}$

so altogether I got: $\frac{1}{2(z-3)} - \frac{1}{(z-4)} + \frac{1}{2(z-5)}$

Now, I need to find the Laurent series at $z=3$ in $ 1<|−3|<4$. I'm not too sure how to progress from here. My intuition is to find the power series at $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at  $z=3$ but not too sure what to do after.

Any hints or anything would really help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a start!  Now we need to find a series for each of the terms.

$\displaystyle \frac{1/2}{z-3}$ is the first series.

$\displaystyle \frac{-1}{z-4} = \frac{-1}{(z-3)-1} = -\frac{1}{z-3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z-3}}=-\frac{1}{z-3}\left(1+ \frac{1}{z-3}+ \frac{1}{(z-3)^2} +  \frac{1}{(z-3)^3}+\cdots \right)$

Similarly for the third term.

Comment: Thanks! Helps alot. I'm assuming that once we find the series for all 3 terms, we add each series together? Or do we keep them seperate?

Comment: You are welcome.  We add them, either combine them (most elegant) or just write a sum of all three without simplifying (less elegant, but correct).